# Su v/s Sudo on Mac

Tags: symlink, sudo, su

I was trying to create a symlink to the sublime exe file from the sublime package to usr/bin using su:

```
su ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/
```

but it gave me an error:

```
su: Sorry
```

It seems to work when I use sudo. As far as I was aware (I might be wrong), su switches to root user, whereas sudo runs a command from root user perspective but doesn't switch to it..In that case shouldn't both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

su takes options of it's own, to run a command, try `su -c <command>`